# Problem on logarithms

Tags: logarithms

if lg2=x, lg3=y
,then 
i) 2/9 
 ii) 75
 iii) 0.0015 
Write logarithm base 10 of x and y Please help me to resolve this problem.

For first one I got this, Is this correct? 
10^x=2 
10^y=3 
=10^x / (10^y)^2 
=10^x / 10^2y 
=10^x-2y

Comment: Are you looking for the log of each part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you know the logs of 2 and 3, you need to express each question in terms of 2 and 3 (using multiplication, division and exponents).

So, $\frac{2}{9}=\frac{2}{3^2}$ then you can use the logarithm rules to convert that into $\log2-2\log3$ and you can plug in what you know is $\log2$ and $\log3$.

$$\begin{align}\log\frac{2}{9}&=\log\frac{2}{3^2}\\ & =\log2-\log3^2\\ & =\log2-2\log3\\&=x-2y\end{align}$$